# 5.8 kernel in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, kernel, versions, espeak

I have an Ubuntu 20.04.2 machine and my kernel is 5.8.

In Ubuntu 20.04 the kernel version is 5.4 and not 5.8, while
I've also seen Ubuntu 20.04.2 machines running kernel version 5.4.

Is this a bug? What is the correct kernel version that should be running and why the difference?

Answer (score 3):

A newer kernel indicates that an [HWE Kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) is installed on the LTS release. That is normal behavior.

An older kernel indicates that either:

1. The system is not up-to-date (needs a `sudo apt update`/`upgrade`), or
2. The Admin has chosen to NOT use HWE. Some enterprises choose to keep older kernels to avoid breaking their workflow. Some (advanced) individual users also occasionally make this choice to keep older software working.

---

- Instructions: [How to change to/from HWE](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).
- **Advice**: For most users, the kernel version does not much matter either way. Whether you use HWE or not, just keep your system up to date.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug. The kernel has been upgraded from 5.4 to 5.8 through software updates aka (apt upgrade). You don’t need to worry about it as it doesn’t affect anything for **most** users (especially those using fairly older systems like me). This behaviour is normal.

For example, you updated Google Chrome. Before this, you were using Google Chrome version 83. After you updated Google Chrome, it shows that you are using version 84. This also applies to the kernel. You were using version 5.4 before and now it has been updated to version 5.8.

Ubuntu 20.04 has kernel version 5.4 because it is an old version. It hasn’t been updated. Updating from Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel version 5.4 to Ubuntu 20.04.2 with kernel version 5.8 is like upgrading from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1. Nothing interesting.

Comment: I wouldn't say that "it doesn’t affect anything on your computer". It affects a lot. For example on some AMD GPUs brightness doesn't work on 5.4, but does on 5.8. But on my GPU there is a problem with brightness on 5.8, and I am using 5.4 because of that. :-)

Comment: Wow that’s kinda interesting  Better blame AMD engineers for their poor upstream driver support.

Comment: This is more complex than to blame engineers. The provided support in kernel 5.8, but there is a problem with systemd now.

Comment: i know this but i today installed ubuntu and my kenel is 5.8

Comment: thanks  i know this.

Answer (score 0):

Without the old kernel, you can hardly run the `startx` command. I tried it before and the system told me that I have no options for this, besides, the old kernel helps from the black screen at the time of the global error, otherwise the system can also say that you no longer have any options. The old kernel that is installed by default  not needed deleted. I would like to add it.